# Marker points on plot graph

Tags: matlab

I have a plot of the following data :

```
t=0:0.001:10;
y=0.2*cos(t) + cos(1.4*t) + 0.8*cos(5.2*t) + 0.02*randn(1, 10001);
```

I want insert 8 marker points (I) on the plot, in other words I want highlight these points with Circle or Asterisk

```
I= (1, 1430, 2859, 4288, 5717, 7146, 8575, 10001)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define y as a function, like this:

```
y_fcn = @(t) 0.2*cos(t) + cos(1.4*t) + 0.8*cos(5.2*t) + 0.02*randn(1, length(t));
```

and then plot the points with an asterix:

```
I = [1, 1430, 2859, 4288, 5717, 7146, 8575, 10001]
plot(I, y_fcn(I), '*r')
```

Complete code could look like:

```
t=0:0.001:10;
y_fcn = @(t) 0.2*cos(t) + cos(1.4*t) + 0.8*cos(5.2*t) + 0.02*randn(1, length(t));
plot(t, y_fcn(t), '-b');
hold on
I = [1, 1430, 2859, 4288, 5717, 7146, 8575, 10001];
plot(t(I), y_fcn(t(I)), '*r')
```

Edited my answer! :-)

Comment: The code is not running: Error in ==> Untitled3 at 5
plot(l, y_fcn(I),'*r');